# Java: How do I efficiently merge multiple xml files to create a new xml?

Tags: java, xml, merge

In *Java*:
Suppose I have 3 xml files

```
<student>lin</student> --  file1.xml

<student>Eric</student> --  file2.xml

<student>joe</student> --  file3.xml
```

How can I merge these xml’s (considering that they don’t have the DTD or namespace declaration) to create

```
<class><student>lin</student> <student>Eric</student>
<student>joe</student> </class> -- file4.xml
```

*class* being the wrapping node I supply manually

*Ps*: I used [xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) to create the xml’s

Comment: Is <class> a top level element for the whole XML document, or an existing xstream object?

Comment: @Kaleb top level element

Comment: There is fairly straightforward solutionunless u r seeking a general solution,use XMLNOde objects which point to the Student node in first xml and append them to node in seconf xmlDocument object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I your files are large I would use a **SAXParser** where your [ContentHandler](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html) would echo the tags and the content.

Something like (*pseudo-code*):

```
print("<class>")
foreach(file in files)
  {
  mysaxparser.parse(new Handler() 
     {
     content="";

     void endElement(tag)
         {
          if(tag.equals("student")) print("<student>"+escapeXML(content)+"</student>"); 
         content="";
         }
     void characters(str)
         {
         content+=str;
         }
     },file);
  }
print("</class>");
```

If your files are small enough to fit into the memory: load the DOM of each document using a  [DocumentBuilder](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) and call [importNode](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#importNode%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20boolean%29) to merge the documents into one.

Comment: I'm tempted to give you -1 for that hacky SAX solution, but your DOM solution is all but guaranteed to be the best approach.

Comment: This looks out of the way from OOP concept.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the files are each well-formed you could concatenate them together (after removing any prolog entry from them), along with a header and footer containing the root element start and end tags.

```
String[] filenames = new String[]{"header.xml", "file1.xml", "file2.xml", "file3.xml", "footer.xml"};
OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("merged.xml");
for (String filename : filenames) {
    InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename);
    org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
    inputStream.close();
}
outputStream.close();
```

Comment: This will work as long as the individual files don't have a prologue.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way to do it is to load the three files into DOM documents and  then have one of them adopt the nodes from the other two documents, this way it is all handled by the dom api and sould be foolproof, instead of text manipulation.

You can achieve this by looking into the DomDocument javadoc.